# flinksql read custom format data with json

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

I am trying to read streaming data from `Kafka`, where streaming logs with the format as below

```
03-06-2022 02:56:130 INFO [...] [...] {"a": "abc", "b": 123}
```

I want to extract the `JSON` part from the logs, which is the `{"a": "abc", "b": 123}` part, and load it as a streaming table with columns `a` and `b`. Can anyone provide me with the appropriate config in the Flink SQL table?

Comment: You will have to use the `map` operation with regex on your data stream to extract the `JSON` data from your logs dataset.

Comment: is there a way in flinksql？

Comment: There might be, but I am not so familiar with Flink SQL.